# Backspace in Emacs has effect but does not update display in term and ansi-term (Emacs 23, cygwin)

Tags: emacs, terminal, cygwin

In `M-x term`, I type `ab`, press backspace, then `ab_` is visible (_ is space). Hitting enter tells no such command `a`, so the deletion has effect but the the terminal is not updated correctly. Likewise for `home` and `end` buttons.

I start Emacs from cygwin using dos prompt or mintty, same effect. What chould be wrong?

Comment: @Thomas it tells xterm for mintty, cygwin for dos prompt

Comment: Hm, it says `eterm-color` for me on Ubuntu. Perhaps you could try `export TERM=eterm-color` (assuming bash) and see it that helps?

Comment: same problem: mksh on pcbsd with TERM=xterm-256color (tried `xterm' too)

Answer (score 1):

I have just had this exact problem, also in cygwin, rather than any proper Linux.

As suggested by the comments, the TERM seems the key.  Mine was already `eterm-color`.  Setting it to xterm fixed it for me.

```
export TERM=xterm
```

Obviously there are other values to try if xterm doesn't work for you.